# Override operator using class method in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Is there a way to override a stream operator like `<<` or `>>` by using other class methods, such as read() and write()?

For example,

```
//In the header file
class Customer
{
    void read(istream &, Customer &);
    istream & operator>>(Customer &) = read();

    void write(ostream &, const Customer &);
    ostream & operator<<(const Customer &) = write();
}
```

It is a requested feature from a question in the textbook, no `friend` allowed.

Comment: Then you have to define the operator outside of the class.

Comment: @NeilKirk could you give me an example? Thank you.

Comment: `ostream& operator << (ostream& os, const Customer& customer)`